# Telegraf with firebase realtime database not working in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, telegraf

### Context

- Telegraf.js Version: 3.36
- Node.js Version: 12.16.1

### Expected Behavior

Bot in AWS Lambda with firebase and telegraf should send the value of the realtime database **only once** when asked.

### Current Behavior

The bot is sending the value from the firebase realtime database **indefinitely without stopping**.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create Lambda function (ZIP node_modules and all necessary, files like index.js) and set all environment variables.
   1.2 `index.js` must be:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TOKEN);

const firebase = require('firebase');

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.APPID
});

bot.command('value', (ctx) => {
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  let ordersRef = rootRef.child("last");

  ordersRef.once('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
    let data = dataSnapshot.val();
    ctx.reply(data);
  })
})

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const tmp = JSON.parse(event.body); // get data passed to us
  bot.handleUpdate(tmp); // make Telegraf process that data
  return callback(null, { // return something for webhook, so it doesn't try to send same stuff again
    statusCode: 200,
    body: '',
  });
};
```

2. Create API Gateway -> Add method POST -> Lambda Function -> Deploy -> Copy invoke url
3. Set invoke URL as webhook

---

Maybe the return value of the handler is not being sended to Telegram Servers so they keep sending the same message?

I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/953) in the GitHub repository of Telegraf, but they haven't found what's wrong either.

---

## Update

I notice something.While this code works just fine:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
require('dotenv').config();
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TOKEN);

const firebase = require('firebase');
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTHDOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASEURL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.APPID
});

bot.command('value', (ctx) => {
//  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  ctx.reply("Hello")
})

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const tmp = JSON.parse(event.body);
  bot.handleUpdate(tmp);
  return callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: '',
  });
};
```

Just by uncommenting the reference, it starts failing, replying "Hello" a lot if times again.

The WebhookInfo is saying `"last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 502 Bad Gateway"`.